Having issues with central ac unit in NC
Our Central AC unit is not cooling the house down,  Even at night. It runs all day set at 68f but never gets any cooler than 75-80. We even bought an 8000 btu portable unit to help cool the house thinking if the walls were cooler the ac may run better? But not even running both units at their max can we cool this house down. The landlord says it's just the way it is in summer and we won't get it cooler than 20 degrees difference than outside. But that's not true because it was 96 today and the house was at 82 all day. By his calculations it should have been about 76 in the house. At night it doesn't even catch up. It just stays hot as hell. My daughter has athsma and this is proving to be a difficult situation. Does it need to be serviced? Maybe freon?

is it actually blowing cold air? are you leaving any windows or doors open to the outside?

Yes the unit needs to be serviced.

Have the filters been changed? If not, they can restrict airflow - if restricted too much, the coils can freeze up. Beyond that, it's professional service time, with an uncooperative landlord, good luck.

If the AC is working correctly but the house is poorly insulated, the cooling will be lost.

Note that you might be able to pay for the AC to be fixed then deduct the cost of the fix from your rent, based on "enjoyment of the premises" rules, if the landlord will not cooperate. Get legal advice before doing this.
